# How to force server to redirect on axios get request?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

How am I able to force a server redirection triggered by and axios get/post request?

- cors middleware is enabled
- server doesen't respond with redirecting to other route

```js
// FE REQUEST
const redirectBTN = document.querySelector('.btn-redirect');
redirectBTN.addEventListener('click', async () => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:8000/from');
});

// BE RESPONSE    
app.get('/from', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/to');
});
app.get('/to', (req, res) => res.send('Hello, World!'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ajax` calls are not a "pure" browser request they can't force the browser to redirect to a page (by using headers).

You can use `window.location` to redirect the user if you know the URL.

```
const redirectBTN = document.querySelector('.btn-redirect');
redirectBTN.addEventListener('click', async () => {
   window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8000/from';
});
```

Or you can do an Ajax call and the use  `window.location`

```
const redirectBTN = document.querySelector('.btn-redirect');
redirectBTN.addEventListener('click', async () => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:8000/from')
     .then((res) => {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8000/from/' + res.some.data;
     });
});
```